# I cant delete single line from a text file C++

Tags: c++, string, file, text, structure

Hello i am working on a project where i have students theyr numbers names surnames and everything and i want to choose a student by name and delete the whole information on about the student it is in case 3: My code:`

```
case 3:{


           int fNomer;
           string ime;
           string prezime;
           string familiq;
           string fakyltet;
           string specialnost;
           int grypa;
           int kyrs;
           string stud;
           cout << "Stydenta koito iskate da iztriete";
           cin >> stud;
           ifstream file;
           ofstream outfile;
           file.open("Student.txt");
           outfile.open("newM.txt");
           while (getline(file, line))
           {
               if (line == deleteMovie){}
               else { outfile << line << endl; }
           }
           outfile.close();
           file.close();
           outfile.close();
           file.close();
           remove("Students.txt");
           rename("newM.txt", "Students.txt");
           break;
}
```

Comment: You should format your code correctly. Like in your C++ textbook for example.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  
Please take the [tour],  
learn asking good questions stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask,  
make a [mcve].  
An MCVE should include a variety of sample input (illustrating all aspects) and desired output.  
If you are looking for help with debugging code see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/  
An MCVE would provide information on e.g what deleteMovie is. It is probably part of the failure mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
 while (getline(file, line))
 {
    if (line == deleteMovie){}
    else { outfile << line << endl; }
 }
```

first we format this piece of code correctly:

```
 while (getline(file, line))
 {
    if (line == deleteMovie)
    {
    }
    else
    {
      outfile << line << endl;
    }
 }
```

and now we can see (well we could see if before already) that you are checking against the wrong variable `deleteMovie` instead of `stud`:

```
    if (line == deleteMovie)
```

should be

```
    if (line == stud)
```

You still need to add error checking, for example to handle the case when a file cannot be opened.